# How to fill a column considered a foreign key in ReactTable in React from json file

Tags: javascript

The problem is that I have mapped objects: one to many (example "category" and "product") and the management of the foreign key in a front end application with React.

The backend is with Spring Boot Data Rest.

The columns are like:

```js
class ListProd extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { prod: []};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchProds();
    }
    fetchEtuds = () => {
        fetch ('http://localhost:8080/' + 'products')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    prod: responseData._embedded.products,
                });
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
```

```js
const columns = [{
            Header: 'Id',
            accessor: 'id',
            Cell: this.renderEditable
        }, {
            Header: 'Code Product',
            accessor: 'codep',
        }, {
            Header: 'Label',
            accessor: 'label',
        },  {
            Header: 'Price',
            accessor: 'price',
        }, {
            id : 'category_id',
            Header: 'Category',
            accessor: '_links.category.href', // **my problem is here**
            ...
            return (
            <div className="App">
            <ReactTable data={this.state.prod} columns={columns} filterable={true} pageSize={10}/>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ListProd;
```

the json code is like this

```html
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "products" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "label" : "l1",
      "price" : 100,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
        },
        "product" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/1",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "Category" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/1/category"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "id" : 2,
```

So the problem is that I don't get the foreign key value, but instead the URL of each row, like this:
http://localhost:8080/products/1/category
for the product id=1
witch return the json format :

```css
{
  "id" : 1,
  "nameCat" : "C1",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/categories/1"
    },
    "category" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/categories/1"
    },
    "products" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/categories/1/products",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the value of each category in the list of product listProd?

Comment: Sounds like this is a question for the backend. I guess this question should be tagged Spring Boot Data? Are you not saying that you are making an API request to some endpoint on Spring Boot and this the response? You would like a the response to be different than showing the "href" for the categories/1 you could make another API request for each of those product IDs or categories. Or you can change how the API works.

Comment: Ok, for this example, can i render in a form field the value of the category (1 here)